# Sum a quantity list in an array

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have an array table using ARRAYFORMULA({Fruit Names, Quantity}) that looks like

```
| Apples  |  2 |
| Oranges |  3 |
| Bananas |  5 |
| Oranges | -2 |
| Bananas | -1 |
| Apples  |  1 |
```

I'd like to sum all the unique items into one list into:

```
| Apples  |  3 |
| Oranges |  1 |
| Bananas |  4 |
```

Without referencing specific cells (I populated the arrayformula from other data). Any way to do this without referencing cells and using only arrayformula?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution with

```
Query(ARRAYFORMULA, "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1<>'' group by Col1")
```